# How to get all available persistentStores in my ubiquityContainer?

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, nspersistentstore

In my application I have several persistent stores and the user can remove and add stores. I recently added iCloud to the project and now I need to know which stores are available on startup so that I can list them. Previously this was handled by array that I managed upon creating and removing stores. But now that stores can be created or removed or a separate device I would like to get all persistent stores available in my ubiquity container. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I use to look for new or deleted files.  Post any questions you have and I will do my best to respond.

```
/*!  Creates and starts a metadata query for iCloud files

 */
- (void)createFileQuery {
    [_query stopQuery];

    if ([[CloudManager sharedManager] isCloudEnabled]) {
        if (_query) {
            [_query startQuery];
        }
        else {
            _query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];

            [_query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope, NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDataScope, nil]];
            NSString *str = @"*";
            [_query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, str]];

            NSNotificationCenter* notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
            [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(fileListReceived) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:_query];
            [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(fileListReceived) name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:_query];
            [_query startQuery];
        }
    }

}

/*!  Gets called by the metadata query any time files change

 */
- (void)fileListReceived {
    //LOG(@"fileListReceived called.");

    bool found = NO;

    if ([self getNewiCloudDocs]) {
        //LOG(@"  New iCloud documents found!");
        found = YES;
    }

    if ([self getDeletediCloudDocs]) {
        //LOG(@"  Deleted iCloud documents found!");
        found = YES;
    }

    // Just check the local files again...
    if (found)
        [self updateList];

    return;

}

/*! Gets the list of files in the iCloud directory and compares against files we have locally
    and then creates new ones if required.  WARNING: files appear in iCloud before they appear
    locally when we are creating new documents so we must set a flag so we know to ignore any 
    new files that appear if we are busy creating a new document already.  Only applies if we
    have initiated creating a new document on this device!

    @return Returns true if any have been found
 */
- (bool)getNewiCloudDocs {
    //FLOG(@"getNewiCloudDocs called");
    bool found = NO;

    NSURL *iCloudDirectory = [[CloudManager sharedManager] iCloudCoreDataURL];

    //FLOG(@"  iCloudDirectory is %@", iCloudDirectory);

    // Get the top level directory names are these will represent all the iCloud documents
    NSArray* cloudDocuments = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:iCloudDirectory includingPropertiesForKeys:nil options:0 error:nil];

    //Now get an array of the local document names including any UUID because we want then to be unique
    NSMutableArray *localFileIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSURL *doc in _localDocuments) {
        [localFileIDs addObject:[doc lastPathComponent]];
    }

    // Check if there are any we don't already have
    //FLOG(@"  iCloud Documents are:");
    for (NSURL* document in cloudDocuments) {
        //FLOG(@"   %@", [document lastPathComponent]);

        NSString *name = [document lastPathComponent];

        if (![localFileIDs containsObject:name]) {
            //FLOG(@"  new file found: %@", name);
            found = YES;
            [self createLocalCopyOfICloudFile: name];

        }
    }
    return found;
}
/*! Looks for files we have that are not in iCloud and are local.
    These have probably been deleted by some other device so remove them.

    @return Returns true if any have been found
 */
- (bool)getDeletediCloudDocs {
    //FLOG(@"getDeletediCloudDocs called");
    bool found = NO;

    NSURL *iCloudDirectory = [[CloudManager sharedManager] iCloudCoreDataURL];

    //Now get an array of the local document names including any UUID because we want then to be unique
    NSMutableArray *localFileIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *cloudFileIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    for (NSURL *doc in _localDocuments) {
        [localFileIDs addObject:[doc lastPathComponent]];
    }

    // Get the top level directory names are these will represent all the iCloud documents
    NSArray* cloudDocuments = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:iCloudDirectory includingPropertiesForKeys:nil options:0 error:nil];
    if ([cloudDocuments count]) {

        //FLOG(@" %d documents found in iCloud", [cloudDocuments count]);
        //FLOG(@"   docs are: %@", cloudDocuments);
        for (NSURL* doc in cloudDocuments) {
            [cloudFileIDs addObject:[doc lastPathComponent]];
        }

        // Check if there are documents that we have that are not in iCloud
        //FLOG(@"  Deleted iCloud Documents are:");
        for (NSURL* document in _localDocuments) {
            NSString *name = [document lastPathComponent];

            if (![cloudFileIDs containsObject:name]) {
                FLOG(@"  REMOVED iCloud file detected: %@", name);
                found = YES;
                [self removeLocalCopyOfiCloudFile: name];

            }
        }
    } else {

        FLOG(@" no documents found in iCloud");
        FLOG(@" removing all local documents");

        for (NSURL* document in _localDocuments) {
            NSString *name = [document lastPathComponent];
            //FLOG(@"  removing local file %@", name);
            found = YES;
            [self removeLocalCopyOfiCloudFile: name];
        }

    }

    return found;
}

- (void)createLocalCopyOfICloudFile:(NSString *)fileName {

    if (!_creatingDocument) {
        NSURL* fileURL = [[[CloudManager sharedManager] documentsDirectoryURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        [self.appDelegate createLocalCopyOfCloudFile:fileURL];
    } else {
        LOG(@"Busy creating document so don't do anything!");
    }
}

- (void)removeLocalFile:(NSString *)fileName {
    LOG(@"");
    FLOG(@"  REMOVING local copy of file: %@", fileName);
    NSURL* fileURL = [[[CloudManager sharedManager] documentsDirectoryURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [self deleteDocumentAtURL:fileURL];
    LOG(@"");
}

- (void)removeLocalCopyOfiCloudFile:(NSString *)fileName {
    LOG(@"");
    if (!_deletingDocument) {
        FLOG(@"  REMOVING local copy of DELETED iCloud file: %@", fileName);
        NSURL* fileURL = [[[CloudManager sharedManager] documentsDirectoryURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        [self deleteLocalCopyOfiCloudDocumentAtURL:fileURL];
        LOG(@"");
    } else {
        LOG(@"Busy deleting document so don't do anything!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a metadata scan of the ubiquity container and get a list of all the directories in your apps ubiquity containers /CoreData directory.  These directories should correspond with the NSPersistentStoreUbiquityNameKey's of all the stores synced via iCloud. I seem to recall Apple's wwdc2013 207 video explains this is how Core Data/iCloud integration works.

I use a string comprising the user entered filename+'*UUID*'+uuid as the NSPersistentStoreUbiquityNameKey so its easy to present the same filename to the user on another device.

I scan for the presence of 'new' files like this and when I detect one I automatically **build the local copy of the store**, similarly when I detect a file has been removed I remove the local store automatically.

Note that I also store local metadata about a file so that when opening it I can be sure I am passing the correct options to the persistentStoreCoordinator.

I can post the code I use to do the scan if you are interested.

NOTE: Just remember the store itself is not stored in iCloud, only the transaction logs are, so you need to build the local store passing in the correct NSPersistentStoreUbiquityNameKey and Core Data will then import the transaction logs from iCloud.

Comment: I tried a metadata approach in accordance with [link](http://samvermette.com/312) but I did not receive any notification upon on adding a new file on another device.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I use the metadata query to trigger a directory scan.  See the additional answer for the actual code.  hope this helps.